# How to set focus postion to cursor position in an input field with jquery?

Tags: jquery, input, cursor, focus

I created an editable table like this one: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425

But when you click on a table cell you can only navigate with the keyboard. I want to get a better usability through enabling mouse navigation because there are some long texts within the input fields. I downloaded the jquery caret plugin: http://www.examplet.org/jquery/caret.php

But now I dont know how to set the focus position in an input field to the cursor postion.
Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: did you try focus(); method?

Comment: the focus() method doesn't give the focus position back, does it? At least there is nothing in the documentation about it: http://api.jquery.com/focus/